# Export Qlik Sense Enterprise Visualizations in PDF format

Tags: pdf-generation, qliksense

We are looking for different options to export Qlik Sense Enterprise Visualizations in PDF files.
Do any of the JavaScript APIs, other than the Capability API expose methods that can be utilized to convert the information into PDF format?
Do any of the C# .NET SDK libraries expose similar functionality?
Are there any open source custom built projects to do that?
Thank you for the hint!

We used the Capability API in the past and since we are moving away from it, we need to replace the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the other Qlik APIs support PDF exports yet. You have a few things you could try, though:

### Undocumented `/printing` API for QSEoW

The `/printing/` API for the on-prem version of Qlik Sense is what is used behind the scenes whenever a user right-clicks on a chart and chooses to Export to PDF. You could do some reverse engineering to take advantage of that API for your own purposes, whether that's using JavaScript, C# .NET or what have you. [This Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/May2023/Subsystems/Extensions/Content/Sense_Extensions/Howtos/extensions-enable-export.htm) has *some* information about the API.

I think the basic idea is:

1. Make a call to `https://QlikServer/printing/export/object/pdf?requestId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, giving a unique GUID for the request ID.

```js
fetch("https://QlikServer/printing/export/object/pdf?requestId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  },
  "body": "{\"width\":297,\"height\":210,\"dpi\":200,\"fitCriteria\":\"0\",\"margin\":{\"right\":10,\"left\":10,\"top\":10,\"bottom\":10},\"sourceSize\":{\"width\":475,\"height\":267,\"dpi\":96},\"objTree\":{\"id\":\"zAKAcp\",\"type\":\"barchart\",\"snapshotData\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"qInfo\\\":{\\\"qId\\\":\\\"rUSsMp\\\",...",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

2. Poll the `/printing` API for the status of the PDF generation with `https://qlikdev/printing/export/request/status?requestId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`.

```js
fetch("https://qlikdev/printing/export/request/status?requestId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  },
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

You should eventually get a response that includes the download URI:

```
{
    "status": "Completed",
    "error": null,
    "qUrl": "../tempcontent/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf?serverNodeId=zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
}
```

3. Call the `/tempcontent` endpoint to grab that newly generated PDF using `https://qlikdev/tempcontent/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf?serverNodeId=zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz`.

```js
fetch("https://qlikdev/tempcontent/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf?serverNodeId=zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
  },
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

### Reporting API for Qlik Cloud

If you are using Qlik Cloud, you can make use of the [Reporting API](https://qlik.dev/embed/generate-reports/reporting-api-samples), which is a public and documented API for doing exactly what you are hoping to achieve, namely [exporting sheets and charts to PDF](https://qlik.dev/embed/generate-reports/reporting-api-samples/#export-a-sheet-as-pdf-with-default-sheet-size).

### Qlik nPrinting API

If you have the [Qlik nPrinting](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/nprinting/May2023/Content/NPrinting/Introduction/Get-started.htm) product, you can make use of [its API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/nprinting/May2021/APIs/NP+API/index.html) to generate your PDF reports. It's not as "nimble" as any of the other options but it's a bit [easier to design](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/nprinting/May2023/Content/NPrinting/GettingStarted/Publish-simple-report-QlikSense-app.htm) how you ultimately want your PDFs to look and then just generate those reports when needed.

### Headless browser screenshots

You could consider using the likes of [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to programmatically run a headless browser to [grab screenshots](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#takeelementscreenshot) of charts or sheets to then be rolled into a PDF. Or, even easier, you could hone in on sheets or specific charts using the [Single Integration API](https://qlik.dev/embed/embed-quick-starts/single-integration-getting-started) and then using the headless browser to "[print to PDF](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#print-page)."